# Cómo obtener el usuario actual de Windows desde Java

Tags: java, windows

¿Cómo puedo obtener el nombre del usuario actual que ha iniciado sesión en Windows desde Java?

Comment: ¿Qué intentaste? Es importante mostrar tus esfuerzos a la hora de plantear una pregunta aquí. Echa una ojeada a [ask].

Answer (score 5):

Mediante el método [`getProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty-java.lang.String-) de [`System`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html):

```
System.getProperty("user.name");
```

En [este enlace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) puede ver todas las propiedades del sistema a las cuales tienes acceso.

Comment: Esta forma funciona al lado del servidor, necesito obtener el usuario pero al lado del cliente, les agradezco mucho si me pueden ayudar

Comment: Si cualquier script del lado cliente pudiese tener acceso al sistema de archivos del usuario, sería el equivalente a dejar tu puerta abierta para que todos puedan ver el interior de tu casa. Simplemente no es posible.

Answer (score 4):

Usa System.getProperty:

```
String a = System.getProperty("user.name");
```

Referencia:

[System Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html)

Answer (score 2):

Puedes obtener el nombre del usuario actual a través de:

- La variable de ambiente **`USERNAME`**:

  ```
  String usr = System.getenv("USERNAME");
  ```
- La propiedad del sistema **`user.name`**:

  ```
  String usr = System.getProperty("user.name");
  ```
- El comando `net user %USERNAME%`:

  Puedes obtener más información del usuario a través del comando `net user %USERNAME%`. Por ejemplo, su nombre completo, tal como aparece en su configuración:

  [image: conf]

  Esto es, ejecutando el comando desde Java:

  ```
  Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C net user %USERNAME%");
  try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(process.getInputStream())) {
      sc.useDelimiter("\\A");
      if (sc.hasNext()) {
          System.out.println(sc.next());
      }
  }
  ```

  Cuya salida podría ser semejante a la siguiente:

  ```
  User name                    anonymous
  Full Name                    
  Comment                      
  User's comment               
  Country/region code          000 (System Default)
  Account active               Yes
  Account expires              Never

  Password last set            4/21/2017 5:47:47 PM
  Password expires             Never
  Password changeable          4/21/2017 5:47:47 PM
  Password required            No
  User may change password     Yes

  Workstations allowed         All
  Logon script                 
  User profile                 
  Home directory               
  Last logon                   4/21/2017 4:49:20 PM

  Logon hours allowed          All

  Local Group Memberships      *Administrators       
  Global Group memberships     *None                 
  The command completed successfully.
  ```